# How to display single comma separated value in MySql when input keyword in search bar

Tags: php, mysql

I created a search bar using LIKE '%$keyword%'.

My DB:

| title | Name |
| --- | --- |
| IOT | Sara,Husna |
| management | Mia,Sara |

When i searched 'Sara' the result i get is:

Sara,Husna

IOT

I need the result to be :

Sara

IOT,management

I have also tried to do explode but it appear both name while it just need to display the name that is input in the search bar. I am confused.

*Note that i have to use comma separated value in the DB.

Comment: if the string is `Sara, Husna, Sarah, Peter` , then what do u want to display when u search Sara ?

Comment: "_Note that i have to use comma separated value in the DB_" Why would that be? Makes things more complicated.

Comment: you should take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: It may be simple if you do not show the result from the name field, just from the title field. You can shot the searched string instead of the  name field.

Comment: The root of your problem really is the mistake of storing comma separated values in a single field in your database. Learn about database normalisation. You say you "have" to use comma-separated values, but don't explain why. There's generally always an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Your search would be like this and using GROUP_CONCAT, if you are searching  for one prosin.

Like the comments already said it is preferred to used normalized tables without comma delimited data see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

The Name for that you are search you don't need in the query, if you don't want to, because you send it in your form via GET or POST, but you can add it in your search query as constant

Last take also a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) you want to use prepared statements with parameters when you handle dta that are entered

> ```
> CREATE TABLE searbar (
>   `title` VARCHAR(10),
>   `Name` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO searbar
>   (`title`, `Name`)
> VALUES
>   ('IOT', 'Sara,Husna'),
>   ('management', 'Mia,Sara');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) FROM searbar WHERE `Name` LIKE '%Sara%'
> ```
>
> ```
> | GROUP_CONCAT(title) |
> | :------------------ |
> | IOT,management      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=daea8467e40acb040ed28e2675672de2)*